# Zebra ZT410 printing void RFID

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using a Zebra ZT421R for printing a very simple label with a single encoded RFID tag.
AS Example:

```
^XA
^RFW,H^FD11112222^FS
^XZ
```

This one worked. But when I try to encode a RFID Tag, which has more than 96 Bits:

```
^XA
^RFW,H^FDD8A2CECD3AF6C73C74E12E34DA2DF9E74842^FS
^XZ
```

the printer prints a lot of voids...

After some research I figured out that the printer is working with the EPC Memory (96-Bit) and I have to increase the length of the Bit.

Currently, I am using the following ZPl-Command through the example I found on this link:

https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Defining-The-Size-Of-The-EPC-Data-That-Can-Be-Encoded-For-GEN2-RFID-Tags?language=en_US

```
^XA^RFW,H,1,2,1^FD4800^FS
^RFW,H,2,18,1^FDD8A2CECD3AF6C73C74E12E34DA2DF9E74842^FS^XZ
```

In the end I am still facing the same issue with void.
Do you know a way to fix this problem? Is it possible to change the memory size of EPC/PC Bit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the RFID label that you are trying to program has more than 96bit of EPC memory available? What is the brand/make?

Comment: @Danny I am pretty sure it has. 
Through my research I also found this information for the Series of this printer:

epc = reads the EPC data based on the EPC size specified in the RFID tag’s protocol bits, up to 160 bits
Default: epc

Comment: I think the Zebra example is actually wrong, as the PC control specifies the number of words, and not the number of bytes. You have specified 9 words, so 18 bytes, so 36 characters, and everything seems to match-up.

Even if you do something wrong here, it should not yield voids.

You can enable the log using `! U1 setvar "rfid.log.enabled" "yes"` and then retrieve *why* it failed using `! U1 getvar "rfid.log.entries"`.

Or use a platform like Nedap Harmoy (Nedap-harmony.com) to have all this functionality in a nice GUI.

Comment: One more Question => Before using this method I used the following ZPL-Command:^RFW,A^FDD8A2CECD3AF6C73C74E12E34DA2DF9E74842^FS. This worked, but I wanted to encode it in Hex on the first place, so I replaced the "A" with a "H" but it ended in VOIDS. Do you have a clue why it doesn't work this way? Thanks in advance. i will check your above mentioned suggestion in the following week.

Comment: Not a clue to be honest. If you can use the RFID log to figure out the error code, that would be helpful :).